# Exclude var and json file from webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack, external, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to exclude but retain external reference to a few JSON files from a webpack build.

I've modified the webpack.config.js to include:

```
externals: {
        "../package.json": "package_json",
        "./font.json": "font"  
},
```

This solved some previous errors, but now it seems that the 'font' var is being considered undefined.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: font is not defined
```

The error is referring to this line in the build, where webpack has exported the 'font' var as a module.export:

```
/!***********************!
!*** external "font" *!
********************/
/**/ function(module, exports) {

module.exports = font;
```

When comparing the original code to the webpack build, webpack converted this:

```
var font = require('./font.json'),
    Theme = require('./theme'),
    style = require('./utils').style;
```

to this:

```
'use strict';

var font = __webpack_require__(/*! ./font.json */ 334),
    Theme = __webpack_require__(/*! ./theme */ 324),
    style = __webpack_require__(/*! ./utils */ 326).style;
```

Which seems to leave 'font' undefined?  How is webpack handling this var value here?

Webpack is somewhat new to me.  Any insights into how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with json-loader: [npmjs.com/package/json-loader](https://npmjs.com/package/json-loader)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14799757)

Comment: @DeepakMahakale the asker posted the solution he found to his problem. It qualifies for an answer.

Comment: @Cristik It will be better if he elaborate the answer a bit. It seems more of a comment than an answer

Comment: And that's why someone flagged it as low quality post

Comment: @DeepakMahakale bad spelling or some missing explanations don't disqualify this as an answer. If other people run into the same problem, then they should be able to find the answers that address the problem. We should not delete answers because they're in a bad shape.\